# Elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera - Black screen on boot with latest kernel 5.3.0-40-generic

Tags: boot, release-hera, kernel

I am using Elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera on my Lenovo Ideapad S145 with AMD Ryzen 3 3200U CPU. Everything was fine until an update yesterday 18/FEB/2020 which upgraded my Linux kernel from 5.3.0-28-generic to 5.3.0-40-generic.
Since then whenever I boot Elementary OS using the default option, i.e. the latest kernel I am greeted by a black screen instead of the Elementary logo.
If it's of any relevance, during install the bash reported that OS could not find any display drivers for 'amdgpu' and 'navi20' or something similar. I am presently using the older kernel to use my computer. Kindly resolve this issue or suggest a workaround, as I am new to Linux and do not know any better.
Thanks,
Subharthi Kar

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fairly common. I just had to fix it on a fresh install.

Temp fix: In grub menu, highlight elementary option. Click e to edit. Find the *menuentry 'elementary'* line. 
Look for the line that looks like this:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Edit it to add nomodeset. Shoudl look like this when done:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root ro  quiet splash nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

Hit F10 to boot into elementary OS.

Once there, make nomodeset permanent.
In the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add nomodeset. It should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Press ctrl+o, then enter (it prompts for the file to output to, default is generally the file you opened).

Press ctrl+x to exit.

If you have/prefer gedit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Make the same edit and save.

Once your edit is done, enter this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```